# React — catch wheel event on overflow:hidden element?

Tags: reactjs

How can I catch a scroll / wheel event in a React component if the element has overflow: hidden?

Something like this:

```
<Component onWheel={this.handleWheel.bind(this)}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

So I found your question since I was running on a similar issue. My problem was that my div was not scrollable and I needed to capture the scroll event or the wheel move really. This what I did:

```
   export default class MyComponent extends Component {
      constructor(){
        super();
      }

      handleScroll(e) {
        console.log('Scroll event is being called', e);
      }

      componentDidMount() {
          const holder = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.holder)
          holder.addEventListener('mousewheel', this.handleScroll);
      }

      componentWillUnmount() {
          const holder = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.holder)
          holder.removeEventListener('mousewheel', this.handleScroll);
      }

      render() {


        const hiddenRecipients = amountOfRecipients - children.length;


        return (
          <div className="my_holder" ref="holder" />)
}
}
```

So basically I just added a ref and attached an event listener to the mouse wheel.

Hope it helps

Comment: For me it's not working. Function "handleScroll" executes only once when component mounts and then scrolling is not detected any more.

Answer (score 0):

```
const onWheel = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(e.deltaY)
}

<Component onWheel={onWheel} />
```

It's just another way to handle (catch) wheel data in react

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.